# How do I change my code to start Blinking at the same time, and still be infinite?

Tags: javascript

How do I change my code to start Blinking at the same time, and still be infinite?

```
function blink() {
 if (!toggleSwitch) {

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   shapes.push(elements[i].className);

  }
  // Start off at the first element.
  let i = 0;
  let len = shapes.length;

  // Do the next link
  function doNext() {

   let element = shapes[i];
   i++;

   eval(element).fillColor = eval(element).setColor;
   document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = (eval(element).fillColor === document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor) ? 'white' : eval(element).setColor;

   if (i < len) {
    // Don't do anything special
   } else {
    // Reset the counter
    i = 0;
   }
 ,  myVar = setTimeout(doNext, 1000);
  }

  // And the code needs kicked off somewhere
  doNext();
 }
}
```

Also I can't toggle Classes because with a drag and drop I can change the background color any time during a running time so I have an object for each shape where I keep what color is the background. –

Answer (score 0):

To have your page call your blink function after a certain pause first how about doing something like this?

```
<BODY onLoad="setTimeout('blink()', 5000);">
```